# Violation POCO with using Description attribute on properties

Tags: attributes, domain-driven-design, poco

I'm programming on DDD (Domain Driven Design) and I want to use description attribute `[Description("xxx")]` and put it on properties. Now is this a POCO violation or not?

Comment: I think this [link](http://www.vkinfotek.com/poco/poco-vs-entity-framework-generated-classes.html) can help ;).

Answer (score 1):

What are you using that description value for? If it is for a user interface, you are probably violating SRP by using a domain business object as a view model.

Comment: No, I don't want use domain business object as a view model but i get property description using reflector for create dynamic exception message.

Comment: That should not be a problem. Attributes that are used inside the domain rules/validations are just metadata. This is different than attributes that drive infrastructure concerns like persistence or serialization.